# NotifyListeners() is not refreshing the UI in multiprovider

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

I have **2 providers**. One for the Firebase logic and the other one for some ui designs. I have issues in my login made on `Firebase` and `Provider`. The issue is that the root page is not updating when i use "`notifylisteners()`" when the firebase user is logged `(Status.Authenticated)` Even though when i hit Hot Restart it shows me the new root page.

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/blocs/unlogged_bloc.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/blocs/userrepository_bloc.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/pages/LoggedPage.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/pages/SplashScreenPage.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/pages/UnloggedPage.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.black,
      statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  return runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UnloggedBloc>.value(value: UnloggedBloc()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserRepository>.value(
            value: UserRepository.instance())
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Lyric Hero',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: HomePage(),
        supportedLocales: [
          Locale('en', 'US'),
          Locale('es', 'ES'),
          Locale('pt', 'BR')
        ],
        localizationsDelegates: [
          AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate
        ],
        localeResolutionCallback: (locale, supportedLocales) {
          for (var supportedLocale in supportedLocales) {
            if (supportedLocale.languageCode == locale?.languageCode) {
              return supportedLocale;
            }
          }
          return supportedLocales.first;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => UserRepository.instance(),
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          switch (user.status) {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return SplashScreenPage();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return UnloggedPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return LoggedPage();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**User_repository_bloc**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

enum Status { Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated }

class UserRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  FirebaseUser _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;

  UserRepository.instance() : _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance {
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_onAuthStateChanged);
  }

  Status get status => _status;
  FirebaseUser get user => _user;

  Future<bool> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future signOut() async {
    _auth.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }

  Future<void> _onAuthStateChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async {
    print(firebaseUser.toString());
    if (firebaseUser == null) {
      new Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
        _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
        notifyListeners();
      });
    } else {
      _user = firebaseUser;
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

**Unlogged Page**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/blocs/unlogged_bloc.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/widgets/AppTitle.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/widgets/Unlogged/BottomMessage.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/widgets/Unlogged/LoginForm.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/widgets/Unlogged/RegisterForm.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/widgets/gradients/BluePurpleGradient.dart';
import 'package:responsive_widgets/responsive_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:page_transition/page_transition.dart';

class UnloggedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _UnloggedPageState();
  }
}

class _UnloggedPageState extends State<UnloggedPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    new Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          PageTransition(
              type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft, child: UnloggedForms()));
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ResponsiveWidgets().init(context,
        referenceHeight: 1920, // Optional
        referenceWidth: 1080, // Optional
        referenceShortestSide: 411 // Optional, default = 360
        );

    return Scaffold(
      body: BlueGreenGradient(
        child: Center(
          child: AppTitle(
            type: 'white',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UnloggedForms extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget horizontalLine() => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        child: Container(
          width: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(120),
          height: 1.0,
          color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(.2),
        ),
      );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final UnloggedBloc unloggedBloc = Provider.of<UnloggedBloc>(context);

    Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      unloggedBloc.setPaddingBottom(50);
      unloggedBloc.setPaddingTop(50);
      unloggedBloc.setAlignment(Alignment.topCenter);
    });

    ResponsiveWidgets().init(context,
        referenceHeight: 1920, // Optional
        referenceWidth: 1080, // Optional
        referenceShortestSide: 411 // Optional, default = 360
        );

    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
                body: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                        onEnd: () {
                          Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
                            unloggedBloc.setShow();
                          });
                        },
                        alignment: unloggedBloc.alignment,
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsResponsive.only(
                                top: unloggedBloc.paddingtop,
                                bottom: unloggedBloc.paddingbottom),
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              AppTitle(
                                type: 'main-gradient',
                              ),
                              Visibility(
                                  visible: unloggedBloc.show,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      unloggedBloc.root,
                                      BottomMessagge(
                                        login: unloggedBloc.login,
                                        action: () {
                                          if (unloggedBloc.login) {
                                            unloggedBloc
                                                .setRoot(RegisterForm());
                                          } else {
                                            unloggedBloc.setRoot(LoginForm());
                                          }
                                          unloggedBloc.setLogin();
                                        },
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ))
                            ])))))));
  }
}
```

**Login Form**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/blocs/userrepository_bloc.dart';
import 'package:lyric_hero/widgets/CustomizedButton.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:responsive_widgets/responsive_widgets.dart';
import 'package:gradient_widgets/gradient_widgets.dart';
import 'package:responsive_widgets/responsive_widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_signin_button/flutter_signin_button.dart';

class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoginFormState();
  }
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  TextEditingController _email;
  TextEditingController _password;
  double _formheight = 550.0;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget horizontalLine() => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        child: Container(
          width: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setWidth(120),
          height: 1.0,
          color: Colors.black26.withOpacity(.2),
        ),
      );

  @override
  void initState() {
    _email = TextEditingController(text: "");
    _password = TextEditingController(text: "");
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserRepository>(context, listen: false);
    ResponsiveWidgets().init(context,
        referenceHeight: 1920, // Optional
        referenceWidth: 1080, // Optional
        referenceShortestSide: 411 // Optional, default = 360
        );
    ScreenUtil.instance = ScreenUtil.getInstance()..init(context);
    ScreenUtil.instance =
        ScreenUtil(width: 750, height: 1334, allowFontScaling: true);
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsetsResponsive.only(top: 30, right: 20, left: 20),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          ContainerResponsive(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: _formheight,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 15.0),
                      blurRadius: 15.0),
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      offset: Offset(0.0, -10.0),
                      blurRadius: 10.0),
                ]),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0, top: 16.0),
              child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('signin-title'),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(45),
                            fontFamily: "Poppins-Bold",
                            letterSpacing: .6)),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
                    ),
                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('email'),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                            fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(26))),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _email,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          setState(() {
                            _formheight = 620;
                          });
                          return AppLocalizations.of(context)
                              .translate('email_empty');
                        }

                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                              .translate('email')
                              .toLowerCase(),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(23))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(30),
                    ),
                    Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('password'),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                            fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(26))),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: _password,
                      obscureText: true,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          setState(() {
                            _formheight = 620;
                          });
                          return AppLocalizations.of(context)
                              .translate('password_empty');
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                              .translate('password')
                              .toLowerCase(),
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.grey,
                              fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(23))),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setHeight(35),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('forgot-btn'),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium",
                              fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(28)),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    user.status == Status.Authenticating
                        ? Center(
                            child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsResponsive.only(top: 40),
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          ))
                        : CustomizedButton(
                            width: 700,
                            height: 100,
                            color1: Color(0xFF17ead9),
                            color2: Color(0xFF6078ea),
                            text: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                .translate('signin-btn'),
                            action: () async {
                              print("EMAIL: " + _email.text.toString());
                              print("PASSWORD: " + _password.text.toString());

                              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _formheight = 550;
                                });
                                if (!await user.signIn(
                                    _email.text, _password.text)) {
                                  print(Text("something is wrong"));
                                }
                                /*_key.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                  content: Text("Something is wrong"),
                                ));()
                                */
                              }
                            })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsetsResponsive.only(top: 20, bottom: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                horizontalLine(),
                Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('social-title'),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: ScreenUtil.getInstance().setSp(35),
                        fontFamily: "Poppins-Medium")),
                horizontalLine()
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SignInButton(
            Buttons.Facebook,
            mini: false,
            text: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('fb-login-btn'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          SignInButton(
            Buttons.Google,
            mini: false,
            text: AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('go-login-btn'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ]));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

edit Jan 21, 2020

change this

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider<UnloggedBloc>.value(value: UnloggedBloc()),
ChangeNotifierProvider<UserRepository>.value(
            value: UserRepository.instance())
```

into

```dart
ChangeNotifierProvider(create:()=>UnloggedBloc()),
ChangeNotifierProvider(create:()=>UserRepository.instance())
```

make sure HomePage's top child is Consumer

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer(
        builder: (context, UserRepository user, _) {
          switch (user.status) {
            case Status.Uninitialized:
              return SplashScreenPage();
            case Status.Unauthenticated:
            case Status.Authenticating:
              return UnloggedPage();
            case Status.Authenticated:
              return LoggedPage();
          }
        },
      );
  }
}
```

On the comment, you asked me "UserRepository" is working but UnloggedBloc is not called? could you show your UnloggedBloc code?

Your code using UnloggedBloc seems Okay to me. But because of the timer code. It will build every 2 seconds.
I recommend `after_layout` library. Please check this out.

```dart
Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
      unloggedBloc.setPaddingBottom(50);
      unloggedBloc.setPaddingTop(50);
      unloggedBloc.setAlignment(Alignment.topCenter);
    });
```

---

Why do you have two same ChangeNotifierProvider for UserRepository?
From "HomePage", remove the first tree ChangeNotifierProvider.
Put Consumer on the top

And try to use debug mode.

When you call notifyListeners(), check if `build()` callback is working.

Comment: it works alone with that solution you said, but the login isn't work when i want to use my other provider class too, which is also for another functionality.

Comment: When i try to change it, it gives me an error and it says this:             
The argument type 'UnloggedBloc Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ChangeNotifier Function(BuildContext)'.dart(argument_type_not_assignable)

Comment: check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59833201/navigator-push-loses-my-provider-on-firebase-login